# How to get errors from Android device?

Tags: android

When an .apk is deployed and downloaded to Google Play, if it crashes the user can upload an Error report of the stack trace. If we have an internal QA team and .apk has been deployed from dev's PC to device directly, is there away to collect that error stack trace without being tethered to a PC or having the app deployed to the public?

Answer (score 3):

One method that I have used is to add my own default exception handler in all threads, including the UI thread using

```
Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(
            new MyDefaultExceptionHandler(this));
```

and in MyDefaultExceptionHandler I save the uncaught exception to file and let the normal processing happen i.e the app crashes. When the next time app starts and finds a crash report file, it presents the user with dialog asking if the crash report should be sent to developer. If the user selects "YES" then I email the stack trace from the file to my self and remove/clear the file.

Answer (score 3):

[ACRA](http://code.google.com/p/acra/wiki/BasicSetup) is a free library that you can easily include and use in your application, to automatically post all crash reports to a GoogleDoc form.

From their description:

> ACRA allows your Android application to send Crash Reports to various
>   destinations:
>
> - a Google Docs spreadsheet (default and original behavior)
> - an email
> - your own server-side HTTP POST script (
> - any other possible destination by implementing your own report sender

Answer (score 1):

You can use some services like BugSense to collect stacktraces. But to use it application should have android.permission.INTERNET permission.

Comment: This is a most interesting product. Thx!

Answer (score 1):

Install LogViewer, you can see the logcat output on your device.
Works great for me.

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ukzzang.android.app.logviewer

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of  application in Google play like [Log Store](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.xtralogic.android.logcollector&feature=search_result) which testers may use for sending application logs on your email.

Answer (score 0):

Hockeyapp(www.hockeyapp.net) is very useful for this. It helps beta testing without opening your app to public. I have been using it for quite a while now and and it is very easy to upload new versions of the app and get users to update their apps. This is from their website

> HockeyApp is the best way to distribute your betas and collect live
>   crash reports for beta and release apps on Mac OS X, iOS and Android.